# Why does water spread when thrown?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, water

I have noticed that when you throw a bucket of water (or any other liquid), it spreads out. Why does it not stay clumped together like a ball or the shape of the container it was thrown from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the aerodynamic forces applied to it by its travel through the air, which tend to break it up onto droplets, greatly exceed those from its surface tension, which would otherwise draw the body of water into a spherical glob.